# Will the log value be considered in the form of integer(without floating values) or double or round off value

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, logarithm

Trying to find out the complexity of a program and it is logarithmic as the increment is by *2(multiply by 2)

```
int a = 1, n = 16;

while(a < n){
// statement
a *= 2;
}
```

While analysing, 
Iteration 1 --> a = 1 --> 2<sup>0</sup>
Iteration 2 --> a = 2 --> 2<sup>1</sup>
Iteration 3 --> a = 4 --> 2<sup>2</sup>
Iteration 4 --> a = 8 --> 2<sup>3</sup>
'
'
'
'
Iteration k --> 2<sup>(k-1)</sup> = n - 1
(n - 1 because the loop will be executed for 1 less than n times)

Now, I want to find out the total iteration(k) for a given input 'n'
After applying log on both sides

k - 1 = log<sub>2</sub>(n - 1)
k = log<sub>2</sub>(15) + 1
k = 3.90689059560 + 1 (here I am getting confusion to take log value as an integer without fraction or round off value)
eg:
k = 4 + 1 
or
k = 3 + 1

because if I take 4 as value of log<sub>2</sub>, then the 'k' will 5(4+1) and which gives the wrong number of iterations because in the above program, the actual number of iterations performed will be 4
with the provided values.

What might the solution for this problem and suggest me if I am going wrong somewhere in finding out the complexity.

Comment: The loop will execute until `a >= n`. Since `a` starts at 1, and doubles on each iteration, the number of iterations is `log2(n)`. And since the number of iterations is an integer you need to round up.

Comment: I agree with your point that it will execute until a <= n (so as to check for false condition), but I want to get the number of iterations the statement(which I commented in the program) got executed and if I try to solve the formula(made for getting number of times the statement being executed(i e, 2^(k-1) = n), then it will give 5 as the result even though the actual statement got executed for 4 times only.